# how to correctly logout user in spring security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Edit - 1

```
<security:logout
    invalidate-session="true"
    logout-success-url="/logout"
    logout-url="/logoutfail"/>

 </security:http>
```

Edit - 1 end
http://pastie.org/8588538 are the lines 1 to 6 a correct way to logout users? because when I do, the user seems to be logged out momentarily on the page but then can visit other pages again with the same login. it seems  line 31 and 38 is making a new session cookie. but how?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/logout" )
    public String logout(ModelMap model, HttpServletRequest request){
        request.getSession(true).invalidate();
        System.out.println("logout user page shown--------------------");
        return "/login/logout";       
   }


200 OK

GET /logout

200 OK

localhost:8080

5.7 KB

127.0.0.1:8080



225ms
HeadersResponseHTMLCacheCookies
Response Headersview source
Content-Language    en
Content-Length  5864
Content-Type    text/html;charset=ISO-8859-1
Date    Mon, 30 Dec 2013 21:38:59 GMT
Server  Apache-Coyote/1.1
Set-Cookie  JSESSIONID=4B961D14E4B3096368BCC5F9A55874BC; Path=/ttmaven/; HttpOnly

Request Headersview source
Accept  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language en-US,en;q=0.5
Connection  keep-alive
Cookie  JSESSIONID=A0E89C909D0A7F7BE93EC737130E9A31
Host    localhost:8080
Referer http://localhost:8080/ttmaven/users/home
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:25.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/25.0
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how you do it:

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
```

Spring Security also comes with login/logout functionality already implemented, here is how you can configure a custom logout URL.  You don't have to create any controllers/request mappings then.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd">

    <http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
        <logout logout-url="/custom_logout_url" />
    </http>
</beans:beans>
```

Comment: hmm.. why `request.getSession(true).invalidate();` would not work? its invalidating the session and a new (not the previous) one is created. so the logged in session is invalidated. Still I cant understand

Comment: If you are using this XML config: <security:logout
    invalidate-session="true"
    logout-success-url="/logout"
    logout-url="/logoutfail"/>, then you don't need to implement the controller and request mapping for "/logout", Spring Security handles it for you.  Just delete the whole logout() method from your controller.

Comment: then how to logout the user then? 2. I have to show some success / error page after logout or logout fail. no?

Comment: Ooooh, I see what's happening.  By the time you make it to your logout() method, your user should already be logged out.  Then his session is invalidated again.  So in your logout() method, just return the view name, no other method calls.  Also, add a debug DIV to the page and print the current user info in there so you can see who is logged in/not logged in.  Hope it helps.

Comment: thats what is strange. the previous user was "Admin", now I logout, still see "Admin"

Comment: even if i comment out or delete `request.getSession(true).invalidate();`. I am still logged in.

Comment: @Mab - Debugging suggestion: add this bean definition to your security context:  <beans:bean id="loggerListener" class="org.springframework.security.authentication.event.LoggerListener" />  it will output security related events to your log.  Also, take a look at the source code for that class, it makes it real easy to understand how Spring Security signals authentication events.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

HTML Page

```
<li><a href="#" th:href="@{/logout}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-out"></span> Logout</a></li>
```

We just need to map this **/logout** link in our controller.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/logout", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String logoutPage (HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
    if (auth != null){    
        new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, auth);
    }
    return "redirect:/login?logout"; //You can redirect wherever you want, but generally it's a good practice to show login screen again.
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In 2020, you should use [SecurityContextLogoutHandler](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.13.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/authentication/logout/SecurityContextLogoutHandler.html#logout-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest-javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse-org.springframework.security.core.Authentication-).