# Logout user in Spring-Session (Redis) and Spring-security without invalidating session?

Tags: spring, spring-session

Before switching to spring-session [How to correctly logout user in spring security](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848312/how-to-correctly-logout-user-in-spring-security) worked fine. We don't want to invalidate session after the user logs out.

But after starting to use spring-session with redis, the user is not being logged out. I now need to use `new SecurityContextLogoutHandler().logout(request, response, authentication);`

Which causes the session to be invalidated. Is there a way to logout a user without having to invalidate a session?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a [bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SEC-3070) in Spring Security's Logout mechanism. To work around it you can use:

```
SecurityContextHolder.clearContext();
```

Note to work around the issue you should avoid invoking

```
SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(null);
```