# How to logout with Webflux

Tags: spring-boot, spring-webflux

When I login(on loginpage.html) the cookie the jwt-token is placed.

In my controller:

```
 @PostMapping("/login")
    public Mono<String> login(User user, ServerWebExchange swe) {
        return userService.findUserByEmail(user.getEmail())
                .flatMap(u -> {
                            if (passwordEncoder.matches(user.getPassword(), u.getPassword())) {
                                System.out.println("user found");

                                ResponseCookie jwt = ResponseCookie.from("jwt", jwtUtil.createJwtToken(u)).httpOnly(true).build();
                                swe.getResponse().getCookies().add("jwt", jwt);

                                return Mono.just("redirect:/account/accountpage/" + u.getId());
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("user not found");
                                return Mono.just("redirect:/loginpage");
                            }
                        }

                ).defaultIfEmpty("redirect:/loginpage");
    }
```

I'm trying logout, but I still have cookies on the page (loginpage.html). new for Session and old cockie for jwt.

[image]

In my SecurityWebFilterChain:

```
 return serverHttpSecurity.
                csrf().tokenFromMultipartDataEnabled(true).and().
                logout()
                  .logoutSuccessHandler(new ServerLogoutSuccessHandler() {
            @Override
            public Mono<Void> onLogoutSuccess(WebFilterExchange exchange, Authentication authentication) {
                ServerHttpResponse response = exchange.getExchange().getResponse();
                response.setStatusCode(HttpStatus.FOUND);
                response.getHeaders().setLocation(URI.create("/loginpage"));
                response.getCookies().remove("SESSION");
                System.out.println(response.getCookies());
                response.getCookies().remove("jwt");
           
                return exchange.getExchange().getSession()
                        .flatMap(WebSession::invalidate);
            }
        })....
```

How to logout so that all cookies are deleted?
why the cookies stay in the request?

For logout I call :

```
 <form action="/logout" method="post"> <button type="submit">logout</button> <input hidden="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}"/> </form>
```

Comment: You provided filter but how do you call it ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848312/how-to-correctly-logout-user-in-spring-security

Comment: I call : 
  <form action="/logout" method="post">
                <button type="submit">logout</button>
                <input hidden="hidden" th:name="${_csrf.parameterName}" th:value="${_csrf.token}"/>
            </form>

Comment: And what is code for you logout endpoint?

Comment: endpoint for what?